# .htaccess and robot.txt in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Am running a image gallery using Wordpress, the users will download the images, I use a folder called "download" in root of the wordpress. I will hide the images using .htaccess in that download folder as,

```
<Files ~ "\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Will this .httaccess will block Google search? Because my site is fully depend on images. If Google bot blocks, then is there any way to tune it using robot.txt? If so, please guide me.

Comment: This will block _any_ HTTP access to the files.

Comment: What's your reason for blocking the images in the first place?

Comment: @ChrisHerbert : by not blocking the folder with .htaccess, web site images may be directly downloaded and waste of bandwidth. That's why hiding.

Answer (score 0):

This code will block any HTTP access to your images, including Google bot and consequently, the google indexation.
If you really want to block any http access and be indexed, you could except google bot ip addresses. These websites reference Google, Yahoo, MSN bot ip :

http://chceme.info/ips/

http://seofilelist.blogspot.fr/2012/03/google-bot-ip-list.html

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fr/2006/09/how-to-verify-googlebot.html

But, this way isn't a good solution and using robots.txt, that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Ok.. Is there any method to divert the users to home page when then enter the direct url ? For example, I have all images in [root]/download/ . if user enters homeurl.com/download/ they have to redirect to home page homeurl.com